# Hazelcast queue stops working, where to look for the error?

Tags: java, tomcat, hazelcast

I use Hazelcast as a non-persistent queue between two applications running in a Tomcat.

Problem: QueueListener stops listening to its queue. This means, until a certain point, the following line appears periodically in the log, then it disappears:

```
LOGGER.debug("No messages on {}, {}", queueName, QueueListener.this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

There is no error in the logs. I have several class that extends the QueueListener, all of them listen to a different named queue. One of them just stops and I have no clue why, except one thing: it happens right after handling an item. The descendant class's handle method logs the item I can see that in the logs. Then the "No messages on {queuename}" loglines just disappear. The executor had 2 threads. Both stopped, not sure if at once.

The descendant class's handle method executes a Http request and logs the response. Note that the response did not appear in the logs for the previous two `handle` call, before the listener stopped.

The descendant class's handle method does not have any catch block so it will not swallow any Exceptions. No exception was logged in the QueueListener.

My question, how to proceed to find the cause of this? Where to look for it?

The application that send messages into this queue runs in the same Tomcat as the one that listens to this queue. Multicast is enabled (see full HazelCast config bellow). There is an other Tomcat that runs on the same host and some other Tomcats running on different hosts, all connecting to this same Hazelcast instance. They're using the same confing.

Hazelcast version: 2.6

QueueListener.java:

```
package com.mi6.publishers;

import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IQueue;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class QueueListener<T> {

    private static final long TIMEOUT = 10000L;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueListener.class);
    /**
     * queue which is processed
     */
    private IQueue<T> queue;
    private final String queueName;
    @Autowired
    private HazelcastInstance instance;
    private ExecutorService svc;
    private final int threadCount;
    private volatile boolean shutdown = false;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param queueName
     * @param threadCount
     */
    public QueueListener(String queueName, int threadCount) {
        this.queueName = queueName;
        this.threadCount = threadCount;
    }

    /**
     * @PostConstuct Start background threads
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOGGER.info("Constructing hazelcast listener for {}", getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (instance != null) {
            queue = instance.getQueue(queueName);
            svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                svc.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (!shutdown) {
                            try {
                                T item = queue.poll(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                                if (item != null) {
                                    handle(item);
                                } else {
                                    LOGGER.debug("No messages on {}, {}", queueName, QueueListener.this.getClass().getSimpleName());
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                // do nothing if interrupted
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                LOGGER.error("Error while receiving messages from queue:{}", queueName);
                                LOGGER.error("Error while receiving messages", ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Hazelcast instance cannot be null");
        }
    }

    /**
     * call before stop
     */
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        shutdown = true;
        if (svc != null) {
            svc.shutdown();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Event handler
     *
     * @param item
     */
    public abstract void handle(T item);

    public String getQueueName() {
        return queueName;
    }
}
```

This is how Hazelcast is configured:

```
@Value("${hazelcast.multicast:True}")
private Boolean hazelcastMulticast;
@Value("${hazelcast.group:groupNameNotSet}")
private String hazelcastGroup;

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    Config cfg = new Config();
    cfg.setInstanceName(hazelcastGroup);
    NetworkConfig network = cfg.getNetworkConfig();
    network.setPortAutoIncrement(true);
    Join join = network.getJoin();
    join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(hazelcastMulticast);
    cfg.getGroupConfig().setName(hazelcastGroup);
    cfg.getGroupConfig().setPassword(hazelcastGroup);

    QueueConfig sms = new QueueConfig();
    sms.setName("some-queue-name1");
    cfg.addQueueConfig(sms);


    QueueConfig flash = new QueueConfig();
    flash.setName("some-queue-name2");
    cfg.addQueueConfig(flash);

    QueueConfig apns = new QueueConfig();
    apns.setName("some-queue-name3");
    cfg.addQueueConfig(apns);

    QueueConfig gcm = new QueueConfig();
    gcm.setName("some-queue-name4");
    cfg.addQueueConfig(gcm);

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
}
```

Comment: What does `handle(T item)` do?

Comment: @vikingsteve, good question. The descendant class's handle method executes a Http request and logs the response. Note that the response did not appear in the logs for the previous two `handle` call, before the listener stopped.

Comment: Okay. I am guessing that if the `handle` method loses it's way then that may well affect the hazelcast queue negatively. Any chance to override the implementation with a `no-op` handle method, and test that?

Comment: Actually there is a chance. Actually I'm rewriting the handle method to be more defensive and more verbose. Let me get back with test results.

Comment: Can you try Hazelcast 3.3? Hazelcast 2.6 is quite old :)